# Replace contractions TypeError: fix() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'

Tags: python

I have a code to replace contractions in words (e.g. didn't) with expansions (e.g. did not) for text files.

```
import os
import contractions

directory = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test1'
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test1')

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        text = f.read()

        lines = [contractions.fix() for line in filename]
        with open(filename, 'w') as out:
            out.writelines(lines)
```

When executing the code, I have the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\replace contractions.py", line 15, in <module>
    lines = [contractions.fix() for line in filename]
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\replace contractions.py", line 15, in <listcomp>
    lines = [contractions.fix() for line in filename]
TypeError: fix() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'
```

Does anyone know what it means and how to resolve it?

Comment: We can't really debug your code without knowing what `contractions` or `contractions.fix` is, but I'm gonna go ahead and guess that you need to change `contractions.fix()` to `contractions.fix(line)` and change `line in filename` to `for line in f` and remove the `text = f.read()`.

Comment: Bonus advice: you can open the file in 'r+' or 'w+' mode to allow both reading and writing. Don't forget to use the `with` statement!

Comment: Contractions.fix expands contractions in words such as "didn't" to "did not". https://github.com/kootenpv/contractions

Comment: Thank you both! The code is working now!